# How to bind a common property of two ViewModels dynamically? (MVVM, ViewModel-First )

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

A ViewModel1 takes data source dynamically from a Model by importing a .csv file containing data values and their distances. The ViewModel1 has two parameterized constructors. It creates a scatter series and stores it in the Series Collection.

```
private IEnumerable<Series> _myScatterSeries = new Collection<Series>();
```

A View1 is created in response to ViewModel1 using DataTemplates. View1  binds to MyScatterSeries property of ViewModel1 and shows the series representation in scatter chart.
View1.xaml:

```
<Grid Loaded="Grid_Loaded">
   <ext:ChartExtension Style="{StaticResource ChartStyle1}" SeriesSource="{Binding MyScatterSeries}" />
</Grid>
```

I want to create a new View window (View2) and it should load the same scatter series created by ViewModel1 dynacamically, when I open View2 window. I tried using the same above code in View2, but it only shows chart, but now series data points. How can I bind MyScatterSeries property of the ViewModel1 to View2 dynamically?

I cannot use the following because it has problem with constructor arguments.
View2.xaml-

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:ViewModel1/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

I also tried using DataTemplate, adding stack panel and wrapping the two Views, but it is not working.

As it is a ViewModel-First approach, I have created a new ViewModel (ViewModel2) for View2. But I don't know how to bind MyScatterSeries of ViewModel1 to ViewModel2, using code. 
Also, Can I use the same code of View1 to show scatter series in View2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought is to have one ApplicationViewModel which contains both ViewModel1 and ViewModel2, and takes control of syncing the data.

Here's a very rough example that should give you the general idea

```
public class ApplicationViewModel
{
    ViewModel1 ViewModel1 { get; set; }
    ViewModel2 ViewModel2 { get; set; }

    public ApplicationViewModel()
    {
        ViewModel1 = new ViewModel1(someParameters);
        ViewModel2 = new ViewModel2(otherParameters);

        ViewModel1.PropertyChanged += VM1_PropertyChanged;
    }

    private VM1_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "ScatterSeries")
            ViewModel2.ScatterSeries = ViewModel1.ScatterSeries;
    }    
}
```

You could also use this same technique to have both objects point to the same object if you want (no idea how this data is updated or maintained by the user)

```
public class ApplicationViewModel
{
    ViewModel1 ViewModel1 { get; set; }
    ViewModel2 ViewModel2 { get; set; }

    private IEnumerable<Series> _myScatterSeries;

    public ApplicationViewModel()
    {
        _myScatterSeries = new Collection<Series>(); 

        ViewModel1 = new ViewModel1(someParameters, _myScatterSeries);
        ViewModel2 = new ViewModel2(otherParameters, _myScatterSeries);
    }   
}
```

The other option would be to use some kind of messaging system to broadcast a message when VM1 data changes, and VM2 would subscribe to those messages and take control of syncing the data. That's a big subject to go into, but I have a quick overview on my blog at [Communication between ViewModels with MVVM](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/06/05/communication-between-viewmodels-with-mvvm/) if you're interested

And last of all, you could just make sure both View1 and View2 have their DataContext set to ViewModel1 assuming there are no other differences. For example,

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="View1"> 
    <vw:View1/> 
</DataTemplate> 
<DataTemplate x:Key="View2"> 
    <vw:View2 /> 
</DataTemplate>

...

<ContentControl Content="{Binding ViewModel1}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource View1}" />
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ViewModel1}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource View2}" />
```

I don't see how your `.DataContext` is set in your code above, so can't provide any relevant code sample for that, but it's always an option.

Comment: The Views are assigned to their corresponding ViewModels using DataTemplate in MainWindow.Resources.xaml file.

`<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ViewModel1}">
        <vw:View1/>           
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ViewModel2}">
        <vw:View2 />
    </DataTemplate>`

View1 in response to changes in ViewModel1 properties, and View2 for ViewModel2. I have to implement a new algorithm in ViewModel2, on Scatter Series generated by ViewModel1. And I don't want to write same code of ViewModel1 for generating Scatter Series in ViewModel2.

Comment: If both `View1` and `View2` can use the exact same ViewModel then you can use a Named template instead of an implicit template. I'll update my answer to show an example of that, however your specific XAML would probably depend on how ViewModel1 is being added to the UI tree (TabControl, ItemsControl, ContentControl, etc)

Comment: I investigated more and found that  first ViewModels must be loaded when we start the Application.Views are added in tabcontrol. MyScatterSeries gets the series representation calculated from .csv file in ViewModel1, and  View1 displays it by binding SeriesSource to MyScatterSeries. Now , is there a way- 
1) to have MyScatterSeries as a common property between ViewModel 1 and ViewModel2, 
2) and updating MyScatterSeries property in ViewModel1 will also update the same in ViewModel2 dynamically.  [1/2]

Comment: I found one clue, that creating event delegate in ViewModel1 and consuming that event in ViewModel2 may workout(??)..
Ultimately- when I start the application, View2 should also show scatter data as shown by View1, although calculation is done only in VIewModel1. 
thanks Rachel for the guidance.. [2/2]

Comment: @prsds Using the event delegate is one solution. Another would be to use a singleton instance of the object, and have both ViewModels point to it. Or you could probably do something like the 2nd code block in my answer to have one instance in a higher level ViewModel, and pass it by reference to both child ViewModels that will be displayed in the TabControl. Which you choose is up to you, and how your code is designed. I'm not sure how complex your ScatterSeries is, or how much users are modifiying it, but a Singleton might be easiest to implement.

Answer (score -1):

You can programmatically set the DataContext for a View in the constructor like this:

```
//Constructor
public View2()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   DataContext = new ExampleViewModel();
}
```

You could pass in the ViewModel you want to create to the constructor, or store a global variable which contains the ViewModel.

Comment: Not in the spirit of MVVM

Comment: @RyanSearle Yes, if he needs to pass arguments in and does not use any framework, and wants to keep it simple without ViewModelLocator etc.